# How to encrypt Embedded Ldap Password?

Tags: wso2

i can't encrypt Embedded LDAP password in repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml file on Identity Server 5.6.0. 
I encrypted a password in embedded-ldap.xml file.
In "cipher-tool.properties" file i have string:

*EmbeddedLdap.Property.ConnectionPassword=repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml//EmbeddedLDAPConfig/EmbeddedLDAP/Property[@name='connectionPassword'],false.*

In cipher-text.properties i have encrypted password for it.
But when i launch Identity Server i get error:

*LDAP: error code 49 - INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: ERR_229 Cannot authenticate user uid=admin,ou=system.*

How to encrypt Embedded Ldap Password?

Also there is "PartitionAdmin" password in embedded-ldap.xml file. I encrypted it. IS is started normal with this encrypted password.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the scenario and found out that it does not retrieve the value from `cipher-text.properties` file for the "connectionPassword" property in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/identity/embedded-ldap.xml` by following `secretAlias="EmbeddedLdap.Property.ConnectionPassword"`.

Instead, it uses the value defined inline within the `embedded-ldap.xml` file. Because, server startup does not fail if we add the correct password in `embedded-ldap.xml` file as following. (Ps: "test123" is the password I've defined as "ConnectionPassword" for the UserStoreManager in `user-mgt.xml`)

```
  <EmbeddedLDAP>
    <Property name="connectionPassword" svns:secretAlias="EmbeddedLdap.Property.ConnectionPassword">test123</Property>
```

So this seems to be a bug/limitation in the WSO2 Identity Server and you can report it by opening an issue in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues).

However please note that the embedded LDAP is provided only for evaluations purposes. Please use an external user store (LDAP or JDBC) in production environments.

Comment: @Epic555, Great. However please note that the embedded LDAP is provided only for evaluations purposes. Please use an external userstore (LDAP or JDBC) in production environments.